# Customizing output of BLAST?

Tags: customization, bioinformatics

I know this is a very specific question relating to BLAST and Bioinformatics but here goes:

I am attempting to use standalone BLAST (I already have downloaded it and tested it running on the command line) to perform a DNA sequence alignment (blastn).  I need to be able to provide both my own query file (fasta format) and my own database file (also fasta format).

The key is that I want to have the program only output 2 fields rather than the detailed reports that it usually outputs.  I *only* want the highest score and the e-value for the alignment to be output.  The idea is that once I have this working, I can wrap this in my own control program and automatically run it many times with different query sequences and log the scores and e-values.

I know this is a long shot, but does anybody have an idea on how I can go about doing this? The two hurdles for me are using my own database file and customizing the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in fact it's simple: `blastall` has several command line option that will help you:

- to output only the single strongest hit for each query: -v 1 -b 1
- to output in table format: -m 8

so you'll be running something like this:

```
blastall -p blastn -i queries.fasta -d database -v1 -b1 -m8 > resultTable.txt
```

The table output has several columns however. I don't recall the order of columns, but you can use the `cut` tool to select only your columns of interest. For example the following command would select only columns 1, 7 and 8 from the blastoutput

```
cut -d '\t' -f 1,7,8 < resultTable.txt
```

yannick

Comment: Hi Yannick - thank you very much for your answer.  I can almost do everything that I want...please see the updates I posted to my original question..maybe you can help out with that too?

Comment: nevermind, I found the page that lists all the parameters for blastall

Answer (score 2):

Yannick's answer covers how to get the specific output you need from `blastall` - the second thing you're concerned about is using your own database file. Standalone BLAST provides the tools you need for this too.

Along with `blastall`, you should also have a copy of a program called `formatdb`, you can provide this with your fasta sequence database, and it will format it correctly for BLAST. For a nucleotide database, run the following:

`formatdb -i input_database.fa -p F`

This will produce a number of files in your working directory (`input_database.fa.nhr`, `input_database.fa.nin`, `input_database.fa.nsq`) which you can use in your `blastall` command by using the original name of your database (ie, miss off the `.n*` suffix).

HTH

PS `formatdb -h` will give you a full list of options for `formatdb`